# ASP.NET MVC convert an object to a query string, where object has a list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm trying to set up pagination for search results.

My simplified search view model looks like this:

```
public class SearchModel
{
      public string Category { get; set; }
      public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The Tags property is set by a multi-select listbox hence the implementation of a collection. Let's assume Tags has a possible range of values of 1 through 5. When the user clicks "Search", the view model is passed to a controller where it is converted into a query string that looks like this:

```
Page=1&Category=Things&Tags=1&Tags=2&Tags=3
```

This is working correctly and the search results page shows the matching values. Of course, this is for page 1; the pagination has to be built somewhere and I am building those page links into the view using Url.Action(). I am trying to leverage Url.Action()'s conversion of an object into a query string. In this case, the object I'm sending Url.Action() for conversion is the viewmodel, with the only change being the Page property for each page URL.

However, when I send the search model to Url.Action() for transformation into a query string, Url.Action() outputs the object like so:

```
Page=1&Category=Things&Tags=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D
```

All the properties get converted correctly *except* the collections. I do not understand why the controller converts the object into a query string correctly while the Url.Action() method does not. Note that using arrays and IEnumerable made no difference.

I'm looking for a solution that will properly convert the SearchModel object into a query string, where that query string will match what the controller produces. This does not seem like it should be a complicated thing for ASP.NET MVC to do, but nothing I've found so far indicates it is possible without complex model binding or JavaScript/JSON.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Because internally the `Url.Action()` generates the `RouteValueDictionary` based on the `.ToString()` value of each property in the model. You cannot pass a model containing a complex object or collection using `Url.Action()`.

Comment: Best guess is you have a form with the listbox and are posting to a GET method and want to be able to persist the collection of tags (and category) when paging. If so, how the view and controller method so that an answer showing how to solve this can be added.

Comment: @Biohazard, did you figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Using HTTP Get requests for paging like you are thinking, using Url.Action(), there is some way to do this, there is always a way but using HTTP post requests will be more straight forward.

Solving this with HTTP Post requests, storing the current page in a  in your .cshtml View as a child of your form action="/mycontroller/myaction" HTML.

Here is a straightforward tutorial:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/implementing-sorting-and-paging-in-asp.net-mvc.html

After you understand this way, you can start to learn how to do the paging with Ajax so there is no page refreshes like the tutorial above ultimately will be.